# In Windows 10 how to redirect from Edge to Internet Explorer for Active directory group?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11

We want to use on Windows 10 existent web app that support IE 11(avoid porting it to Edge) But we want to avoid confusion of unexperienced users in our domain - after obtaining URL of given application likely they will send request using defalt for Windows 10 browser - Edge. How to switch request to this concrete URL launched in Edge to be handled by Internet Explorer 11 for some Active directory group of users? This should work only for users from given group and concrete URL. Is there some group policy setting?

Comment: Just use group policy to put the shortcut where you want it, then make that shortcut be `iexplore.exe <URL>` it won't matter what their default browser is if you specifically set the shortcut to open internet explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For domain joined machines, you can [use Group Policy to deploy a Enterprise Mode site list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility)